# Как вернуться на папку назад?

Tags: c#

Всем привет вот смотрите у меня есть 2 папки:

Папка1 а внутри Папка2

Так вот, у меня программа лежит в Папке2, но я хочу чтобы она скачала файл в Папку1, но не надо указывать полный путь до папки, т.к она может быть перемещена, нужно просто как-то поднятся на 1 папку вверх.

Comment: На сколько я помню две точки (..) - это переход на коталог выше, а одна точка - корень.

Comment: А как это будет примерно выглядеть в коде?

Comment: Как переход к "Папка2\\..". Вроде так

Comment: @Donil, один слеш - в корень. Точка - это текущий каталог.

Answer (score 2):

```
string path = @"..\Папка_2"; 
//либо 
string path = "..\\Папка_2";
```

Answer (score 2):

Получаем путь к каталогу на уровень выше... ну и так далее можно подниматься.

```
    string PathFolder1 = Path.GetDirectoryName(PathFolder2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте относительные пути в данном случае путь к Папка1 из Папка2 будет выглядеть так "..\"

Comment: Осторожнее с бэкслешами. `"..\"` -- синтаксически неверная конструкция, поскольку `\"` задаёт двойной апостороф в строке.